# Why does my OpenGL reflection fail to clip to the stenciled area?

Tags: opengl, reflection

The below code is nearly identical to the code retrieved from [this NeHe tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/clipping__reflections_using_the_stencil_buffer/17004/). The only difference between my code and the code on the tutorial is that I am using SFML for window context, which should not be relevant. To view the entire source code, [go here](http://pastebin.com/NwPrzDs4). A snippet of the relevant code is below (the comments are from NeHe):

```
// Clip Plane Equations
double eqr[] = {0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};            // Plane Equation     glColorMask(0,0,0,0);                             // Set Color Mask
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);                          // Enable Stencil Buffer For "marking" The Floor
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);                     // Always Passes, 1 Bit Plane, 1 As Mask
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);          // We Set The Stencil Buffer To 1 Where We Draw Any Polygon
                                                    // Keep If Test Fails, Keep If Test Passes But Buffer Test Fails
                                                    // Replace If Test Passes
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                           // Disable Depth Testing
DrawFloor();                                        // Draw The Floor (Draws To The Stencil Buffer)
                                                    // We Only Want To Mark It In The Stencil Buffer
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enable Depth Testing
glColorMask(1,1,1,1);                               // Set Color Mask to TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);                      // We Draw Only Where The Stencil Is 1
                                                    // (I.E. Where The Floor Was Drawn)
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);             // Don't Change The Stencil Buffer
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);                           // Enable Clip Plane For Removing Artifacts
                                                    // (When The Object Crosses The Floor)
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqr);                   // Equation For Reflected Objects
glPushMatrix();                                     // Push The Matrix Onto The Stack
    glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);                    // Mirror Y Axis
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, LightPos);    // Set Up Light0
    glTranslatef(0.0f, height, 0.0f);               // Position The Object
    DrawObject();                                   // Draw The Sphere (Reflection)
glPopMatrix();                                      // Pop The Matrix Off The Stack
glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);                          // Disable Clip Plane For Drawing The Floor
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);                         // We Don't Need The Stencil Buffer Any More (Disable)

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, LightPos);        // Set Up Light0 Position
glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                 // Enable Blending (Otherwise The Reflected Object Wont Show)
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);                             // Since We Use Blending, We Disable Lighting
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.8f);                  // Set Color To White With 80% Alpha
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  // Blending Based On Source Alpha And 1 Minus Dest Alpha
DrawFloor();                                        // Draw The Floor To The Screen
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);                              // Enable Lighting
glDisable(GL_BLEND);                                // Disable Blending
glTranslatef(0.0f, height, 0.0f);                   // Position The Ball At Proper Height
DrawObject();
```

The final result of this code can be seen below: [image: Picture]

How do I alter the above code to cause the bottom (reflected) sphere to appear only on the plane instead of outside of it.

Comment: why not just expand the rectangle?

Comment: You appear to be missing rather important parts of this tutorial.

Comment: @Shog9, could you elaborate a bit more on that comment?

Comment: Well for starters: are you talking about [this tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/clipping__reflections_using_the_stencil_buffer/17004/)?

Comment: @Shog9, correct. That is the one.

Comment: Ok. So remember to include that in your question, since it's kinda important to understanding what you're *trying* to do. Next, explain where and why you changed the code in that tutorial to what you have above.

Comment: Ah, forgot to add the link to the tutorial. Added that as well as complete source code link and description of differences between my code and the tutorial.

Comment: @LucasS: Well, do you actually create a GL context with a stencil buffer? The only relevant line for context creation in your code seems to be `f::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Test");`, and that is not very specific. I don't know SFML, but why do you think changing the code for context creation isn't relevant here?

Comment: @derhass, *facepalm* I thought SFML supported stencil buffer automatically in its window creation function. By adding an additional parameter to customize the context settings, the problem was resolved. Go ahead and post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do you actually create a GL context with a stencil buffer? The only relevant line for context creation in your code seems to be

```
f::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Test");
```

and that is not very specific. I don't know SFML, but why do you think changing the code for context creation isn't relevant here?